# Mutex appropriate for fast single writer / slow readers (cpython)?

Tags: python, multithreading, mutex, shared-memory

In my application, I have one single thread that is performing very fast processing on log lines to produce a float value. There is usually only a single other thread performing slow reads on the values at intervals. Every so often, other threads can come and go and also perform once-off reads on those values.

My question is about the necessity of a mutex (in cpython), for this specific case where the data is simply the most recent data available. It is not a critical value that must be in sync with anything else (or even the other fields being written at the same time). Just simply... what the value is when it is.

That being said, I know I could easily add a lock (or a readers / write lock) to guard the update of the value, but I wonder if the overhead of the acquire/release in rapid succession for the course of an entire log (lets say average 5000 lines) is not worth it just to do shared resources "appropriately".

Based on the docs on [What kinds of global value mutation are thread-safe?](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/library#what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe), these assignments should be atomic operations.

Here is a basic example of the logic:

```py
import time
from random import random, choice, randint
from threading import Thread 

class DataStructure(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.f_val = 0.0
        self.s_val = ""

def slow_reader(data):
    """ 
    Loop much more slowly and read values 
    anywhere between 1 - 5 second intervals
    """
    for _ in xrange(10):

        f_val = data.f_val 
        # don't care about sync here
        s_val = data.s_val

        print f_val, s_val

        # in real code could be even 30 or 60 seconds
        time.sleep(randint(1,3))

def fast_writer(data):
    """ Update data extremely often """
    for _ in xrange(20000):
        f_val, s_val = do_work()

        data.f_val = f_val
        # don't care about sync here
        data.s_val = s_val 


FLOAT_SRC = [random()*100 for _ in xrange(100)]
STR_SRC = ['foo', 'bar', 'biz', 'baz']

def do_work():
    time.sleep(0.001)
    return choice(FLOAT_SRC), choice(STR_SRC)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    data = DataStructure()

    threads = [
        Thread(target=slow_reader, args=(data,)),
        Thread(target=fast_writer, args=(data,)),
    ]

    for t in threads:
        t.daemon=True
        t.start()

    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

This represents the fast log parser (actually being read via a PIPE) doing work on each line, and a slow periodic reader grabbing whatever are the current values at that moment. At any time, another once-read thread could come and go to grab those same values from the data structure.

Is this a situation where a mutex in cpython is not needed at all?

**Edit**

To clarify a bit more... I don't even need the float and string fields to be in sync from the last write. It is ok if the scheduler decides to switch contexts between the float and string reads. I'm just wondering if I even need the overhead of a lock to simply read whatever value is assigned at any moment in time.

My concern is regarding the fact that the writer is going to be looping, on an extremely fast operating, locking and unlocking a lock that is often un-contended.

Effectively assume this is all I care about in the `reader`:

```
def slow_reader(data):
    for _ in xrange(10):
        f_val = data.f_val 
        print f_val
        time.sleep(randint(1,3))
```

Comment: This sounds a bit like premature optimization. I'd start with safe mutex-using code and see how it performs, first.

Comment: @hyde: I agree with you about me trying to save on performance right now. But I still have the technical question about locking, atomic field updates, and a writer that is going to be spinning in a long loop and be doing 95% of the lock/unlock with no contention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a mutex when doing concurrent accesses:

- on composite values, and one of these accesses must modify the value in multiple spots atomically;
- on simple values, and at least two of these accesses are writing.

In your example, the value is composite (2 fields), and the modification operates on multiple spots (these 2 fields), so you should put a mutex to ensure that the reader doesn't get scheduled in between the two modifications.

EDIT: If the reader doesn't care about the fields being in sync, then you don't need a mutex.

Comment: Alright but what if I don't care about the sync between the two fields. I should have just left the string off to not confuse the question. The values do not have to be in sync and I don't mind if the scheduler switches between the two. So are you suggesting I still need the overhead of a mutex for the atomic float field?

Comment: I am assuming that the python interpreter does modify individual struct fields atomically, so that you shouldn't have to put a mutex. It depends on the interpreter and the thread mechanism. For instance, there appears to be support for openMP in cython: in that setup I'd be very cautious about it and probably put a mutex for good measure. However, I don't see how you could use openMP in your example.

Comment: Yea in cpython it appears to me that the individual field assignments are completely atomic and safe. If that is the case, and all I want to do is be able to safely sample whatever the current value is, then I suppose the answer is that a lock is not neccessary.

Comment: Here's [some information](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe.htm) that should shed some light on the topic of atomic operations in python. Note that it concern the reference implementation, and that it's a bit old.

Comment: That link was a copy of information for the python docs I linked...but the comments did provide the insight I need. Sounds like I should still lock, even if its for extremely fast and constant operations. Because I should not be relying on implementation issues as they suggest.

Answer (score 2):

You should lock the container in reader when acquiring a single existing item, but if the item itself is not modified by anything any more and will not get moved, you ca release the mutex as soon as reader has the item.

If item may be modified, you can either get a quick copy and release mutex, or have separate mutex for the individual item, so rest of the container can bw worked on by others. Your case sounds like you do not need to worry about this though.

If you have many readers which should pick oldest unprocessed item, then you need a queue (which might be as simple as index of latest taken item) and a separate mutex for it. This might even be an atomic integer, so you could avoid needing a mutex altogether for the "queue".

Actually, with suitable atomic integer arrangement and polling, you could avoid mutexes completely. An atomic integer index for latest complete item, increased by writer and only read by polling readers. Second atomic integer index for latest taken item, increased by readers, which then start waiting for that index to be ready (if it is not ready yet).

(Readers polling can be avoided by some notify mechanism, but these require a mutex lock or socket, both pretty expensive).

Comment: your lockless approach is great, but it limit the number of consecutive updates the writer can do to the size of the array containing the update events. That said, if the reader polling timelapse is monotonic (or with a very narrow margin), then it certainly does the job very well.

Comment: There is only one single thread in the entire system that would modify the values (the `writer`), and I do not require sync between the float and the str reads. I simply want to allow random reads to sample whatever is currently set. Can you clarify why I would need to lock the entire container? I feel like this question is boiling down to whether I care about having the absolutely most recent float or not, in case the scheduler decides to switch right before the `writer` assigns the float. I don't need a queue either because I don't care about previous values or missing one.

Comment: Also to further clarify the application. The float value is really just a job progress being emitted by the log. All of these readers would be separate clients asking for the current status value. It isn't like a work queue where readers need every single value to perform more work.

Comment: You need to atomically determine what is last value in container. By "lock the entire container", I mean lock the container structure (which tells the last valid value), not locking the values of existing items. Also, if you think of optimizing locking, study happens-before/happens-after semantics, they can play nasty tricks esp. with multiple cores.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It has a lot more technical information than @didierc's but I ended up accepting the other one because it pointed to a link which contained some concrete information regarding not relying on implementation details to ensure atomic operations.